# Active record grouping

Tags: sql, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

```
organization.users.select("tags.name, users.id").
    distinct.joins(roles: [:tags]).merge(Role.active).merge(Tag.interest)

    .group_by(&:name).map do |interest, users| 
      {interest => users.map{ |u| User.find(u.id) }} 
    end
```

## => {Football: [User1, User2, User3, ...], .. }

How to achieve it using only **active record querying** ? The grouping I did above with ruby is totaly inefficient, because it queries database again for every user, but does the job.

I also tried to achieve it with only active record querying like that:

```
organization.users.select("tags.name, users.id").
    distinct.joins(roles: [:tags]).merge(Role.active).merge(Tag.interest).group("tags.name")
```

But it gives me

> PG::GroupingError: ERROR:  column "users.id" must appear in the GROUP
>   BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

Comment: hi, can you elaborate on what query it is you are trying to achieve, and also what is [:tags], Role.active, Tag.interest

Comment: I want to get users grouped by interest tags. Result is like I specified hash with { "interest": [array of user objects] }.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry if I misunderstood your question but I think that it would be way simpler to use your `Tag` model directly. You simply need a `has_and_belongs_to_many :users` in your `tags` model and use an outer join to get everything. If you need a hash with the name of the tag after this, it should not really be a big deal.

```
# user.rb
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :organization
  has_and_belong_to_many :tags
end

# tag.rb
class Tag < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users

  def self.with_users_from_organization(organization)
    self.includes(:users).where(users: { organization_id: organization.id })
  end
end
```